# When does "positive expected value" imply "positive conditional expectation with positive probability"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal G,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal G$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra and $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ $\mathcal G$-measurable map. Assume that $\mathbb E_\mathbb P[X]>0.$ Do we always have $\mathbb P(\mathbb E_\mathbb P[X\mid\mathcal F]>0)>0$? Is there a reasonable condition for this to hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]]=\mathbb{E}[X]>0$. It follows that $P(\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]>0)>0$ by considering the set on which $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]>0$. This is just a restatement of the fact that if $\int_\Omega f> 0$ then $f$ must be positive on a subset of nonzero measure.